# Find the locus of the point of intersection of the tangents of the ellipse $b^2x^2+a^2y^2=a^2b^2$ at the points $\phi$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}+\phi$.

Tags: tangent-line

```
- "a" and "b" are constants.
- "x" and "y" are variables.
- pi=22/7
- ø= an angle
```

I try this question at tangent method. But perhaps I do some mistake.
I take the tangents when intersect make angle $\phi$ and $\dfrac{\pi}{2}+\phi$ and then calculate for finding locus. But I failed at that way.

Comment: Are you asking about the director circle?

Comment: $\pi=\frac{22}{7}$...are you serious?

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-locus-of-the-point-of-intersection-of-the-tangents-to-ellipse-dfrac-x-2-a-2-+-dfrac-y-2-b-2-1-meeting-the-ellipse-at-points-whose-parametric-angles-differ-by-90-circ

Answer (score 2):

Let $(x',y')$ be the point of intersection, then the equation of the polar line (i.e. the chord in this case) is

$$\frac{x'x}{a^2}+\frac{y'y}{b^2}=1 \tag{1}$$

End points of the chord:

$$(a\cos \phi,b\sin \phi) \: \text{ and } \: (-a\sin \phi,b\cos \phi)$$

Hence the equation of the chord is

\begin{align*}
  \frac{y-b\sin \phi}{x-a\cos \phi} &=
  \frac{b\sin \phi-b\cos \phi}{a\cos \phi+a\sin \phi} \\
  (y-b\sin \theta)(a\cos \phi+a\sin \phi) &=
  (x-a\cos \phi)(b\sin \phi-b\cos \phi) \\
  b(\cos \phi-\sin \phi)x+a(\cos \phi+\sin \phi)y &=
  ab(\cos^2 \phi+\sin^2 \phi) \\
  \frac{(\cos \phi-\sin \phi)x}{a}+\frac{(\cos \phi+\sin \phi)y}{b} &= 1 \tag{2}
\end{align*}

Comparing $(1)$ and $(2)$,

$$\begin{pmatrix} x' \\ y' \end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
  a(\cos \phi-\sin \phi) \\
  b(\cos \phi+\sin \phi)
\end{pmatrix}$$

which lies on the ellipse
$$\frac{x^2}{2a^2}+\frac{y^2}{2b^2}=1$$